# MultiColumn Text

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to specify that a text must be in multiple column and column width is defined in percent?

something like :

```
<div style="width:20%; max-height:100px;" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante.
</div>
```

if the text overflow the div bound a new column is displayed.

Comment: You could look at the CSS3 Multi Column layout: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Comment: @BillyMoat you should really post that as an answer, it's what I would have said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably advise having a look at CSS3's Multi Column functionality if you don't have to support older browsers:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported using native HTML. Currently JavaScript must be used to obtain this feature.

See: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/how-to-create-multi-columns-in-css3-and-javascript.html#fbid=uRKNCpHfmWY

Answer (score 1):

This is a JavaScript Solution:

I did an iPad WebApp in my last term at the uni which was supposed be a newspaper app. To get the newspaper like rows we used this jQuery Plugin:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Columnizer

or: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

you can specify the width of your columns, the amount of columns and has quite a few features which might be useful for your purpose. (but we didn't need them actually...)